# QML label in any color except white?

Tags: qt, qml, label

I am using pyQt with QML for creating GUI.
I have one qml file (main.qml) that contains ApplicationWindow.
Inside, I have a label that I want to color white:

```
Label{
        id:lbl_absPos
        /*
        some anchors and stuff
        */

        font.pixelSize: _display_font
        color: "black"

        width: _display_width
        height: _display_height
        
        text: "Simple Text"
        
        background: Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "white"
            border.width: 2
            border.color: "black"
        }
```

I know this code works, because any other color works, e.g.:

```
        background: Rectangle{
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "steelblue"
```

creates a steelblue background color of the label. But when I put "white", i get gray color of the window behind, like it is transparent... how is that possible? Is that a bug or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried your code and it worked fine. I don't see a problem with what you've shown.

Comment: As has already been pointed out in a previous comment, your code works correctly, so I think that the cause of the error is in another part of the code that you don't provide, so if you want help then you must provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. By default, the background of the ApplicationWindow seems to be white but I somehow thought it should be lightgrey.